# Capture Mobile Data Packets

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, packets

I would like to capture packets of the internet traffic of my mobile. I would like to ask that if I install wire shark on my desktop machine, and then make my desktop a wifi hot spot, connect my mobile phone with this desktop powered wifi then Would I be able to capture/analyse packets of my internet traffic of mobile on wire shark at desktop?

Your help is highly appreciated.

(I can try it to see if it works, but don't have access to LAN at the moment and need the answer, Thanks for your help)

Comment: Yes it will work. I ran into the same problem recently and documented the steps at http://mohit.io/blog/windows-capture-analyze-mobile-device-network-traffic/  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example that I did for my undergrad computer security course. It's called **Rogue Access Point**. I will not go into detail, but here is a rough guide.

1. Share your mobile data from your smartphone through USB, and make sure you have internet connectivity.
2. Connect an Ethernet cable from the Ethernet port to a LAN port of a wireless router to your desktop.
3. Rename the service set identification (SSID) to the same SSID provided by WiFi provider (For example, Starbuck WiFi, this was what we did, I do not recommend you do it).
4. Turn on Wireshark and start collecting packet.
5. Use filter in Wireshark to find packets related to Facebook login. Use keyword: datr You will find something like

   Cookie: locale=en_US; c_user=506850624;     fr=02PxKMh4c31xOpTft.AWXeEL4hlFqGE5DB0l5hpcqzlZU.BP2Yvw.3d.AWV3N4cB; xs=1%3AUONPf83CTZsfeQ%3A0%3A1349269748; datr=c_l0TvTFOzJaSVQPYIXjZ2am; lu=Tg2KgC1vKc8eTORy62Su_97w
6. Open Firefox, install any cookie injector Add-on.
7. Navigate to Facebook page and start the cookie injector.
8. Copy everything from fr=, in our case *02PxKMh4c31xOpTft.AWXeEL4hlFqGE5DB0l5hpcqzlZU.BP2Yvw.3d.AWV3N4cB* and paste to cookie injector. And refresh the page. Now you should be logged in to Facebook with whoever uses your WiFi hotspot to access Facebook previously.

Note: Facebook now uses HTTPS by default unless you change it in your Facebook privacy setting. This method no longer works on Facebook. It "might" work on other login pages. You can easily find a guide on how to set this up on Youtube!
Best of luck!